# translate the webform

Tags: views, 7, webforms

I have used the webfrom model and webform localization for translate it ,
i have translate it correctly after a few days the webform translate is dispersal , when i have refresh the string the translate is come back , But now the ***translate does not appear any more*** , i have refresh string and  try to translate it but without any benefit how i can fix it to take the translate...

Comment: try to translate it again and then see if you'll get the same issue.

Comment: i do it .but it does not take the translation